# Editing preview on mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, editor

Would it be possible to add the same edit preview that exists on the regular website to the mobile version? It is really hard to get the formatting right if you don't see what happens.

Comment: The mobile apps do have a preview (or, at least, the iOS one does). Also, you can request the desktop site if you need the preview in a mobile browser.